# snmpd.conf - TImeout with Centos

Tags: linux, windows, monitoring, centos7, snmp

First of all i want to say i did a lot of researches and i read tons of examples for the last 3 days but i didn't find a solution that's why i am posting here.

I would like to monitor services and process that are running on a CentOS 7 server from my PRTG (running on a Windows) so in order to do this i have to configure the snmpd.conf file and using the snmp library with PRTG.

The problem i am facing is that, i don't know how to properly configure the snmpd.conf file. I tried a lot of configurations given on this forum and from others but the result is always the same when i am doing a snmpwalk..I am facing that : "Timeout : no response from localhost" (or from the PRTG server).

I also checked the ping and the firewall but i think the problem is in my snmpd.conf file.

Currently i have the default file without any modifications but if someone could give me explications and/or an example of his configuration i think this could help me.

Regards,

Edit 1 : Of course, i forgot it. By the way it is the default configuration because i did many changes and i lost myself last time..:

com2sec  notConfigUser  default       public

group   notConfigGroup v1           notConfigUser
group   notConfigGroup v2c           notConfigUser

view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1

access  notConfigGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  systemview none none

(I do not know what should i put about PRTG because i am monitoring plenty others sensors wihout problem so i think the configuration of this file could be the solution..)

Comment: Please provide your snmpd.conf, along with your prtg configuration, otherwise it's just blind guessing.

Comment: Yes you're right, i did it.